# Remove Nextline duplicates in string

Tags: java

concern in using JAVA

My txtfile (Library - acting as database) contains below;

```
L7232-TRJCD5/   |  FT1  |   4   |   NS70    |  QUAD |   Fusion  | 70C_VPLGA88
L7232-TRJCD5/   |  FT2  |   4   |   NS70    |  QUAD |   Fusion  | 70C_VPLGA88
L7232-TRJCE5/   |  FT2  |   4   |   NS70    |  QUAD |   Fusion  | 70C_VPLGA88
L7232-TRJCEJ/   |  FT1  |   4   |   NS70    |  QUAD |   Fusion  | 70C_VPLGA88
L7232-TRJCEJ/   |  QA   |   4   |   NS70    |  QUAD |   Fusion  | 70C_VPLGA88
L7232-TRJCEJ/   |  QA1  |   4   |   NS70    |  QUAD |   Fusion  | 70C_VPLGA88
L7232-TRJCEJ/   |  QA   |   4   |   NS70    |  QUAD |   Fusion  | 70C_VPLGA88
```

After using burffered reader and scanner function
lines is the variable.

Next step is using split below;

```
String[] Tokens = lines.split("\\\|");
System.out.println(Tokens[1]);
```

Output displays below;

```
FT1  
FT2  
FT2  
FT1  
QA  
QA1  
QA
```

My concern, since output is structured as nextline
iv'e been pressured to remove duplicates.
meaning i do not know what to use to proceed to next procedure.

Open to suggestions and solutions.

Comment: What is your actual expected output?

Comment: The expected output should remove duplicate and output only provided below;
FT1   
FT2   
QA   
QA1

Answer (score 0):

Just use a set of strings to store the codes.  A set, by definition, cannot have duplicates, so this should solve your particular problem.

```
SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
for (String line : lines) {
    String[] tokens = line.split("\\|");
    set.add(tokens[1]);
}
```

Now iterating over this sorted set should produce the unique output sorted alphabetically ascending:

```
for (String token : set) {
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the elements of output into a Array List and then use Set to remove the duplicates:

```
List<String> arrayList = Arrays.asList(Tokens);

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(arrayList);
for(String str : set){
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: sorry still getting the same output

Comment: FT1
 FT2
 FT2
 FT1
 QA
 QA1
 QA

Comment: String[] Tokens =lines.split("\\|"); 
//System.out.println(Tokens[1]);
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(Tokens[1].split("\n")));
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(arrayList);
for(String str : set){
    System.out.println(str);
}  the output i get: FT1 FT2 FT2 FT1 QA QA1 QA

Comment: You can put output into array list: `arrayList.add("FT1"); arrayList.add("FT2"); arrayList.add("FT2"); arrayList.add("FT1"); arrayList.add("QA"); arrayList.add("QA1"); arrayList.add("QA");` and then pass this array list into HashSet.